# DrRacket's keymap doesn't work

Tags: racket

With DrRacket,v6.0 on Windows7, I want to change the keybinding `"c:/"` to `"tab"`, and use `"Complete Word"` as in the `Edit` menu.
I followed these [instructions](http://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/Keyboard_Shortcuts.html#%28part._defining-shortcuts%29) to write a file but it does not work.
Here is my file's code:

```
    #lang s-exp framework/keybinding-lang

    (define (rebind key command)
       (keybinding
        key
        (λ (ed evt)
          (send (send ed get-keymap) call-function
                command ed evt #t))))

    (rebind "tab" "Complete Word")
```

I added it to the keybindings but nothing happens when I press the `tab` key.
Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Have you first tried with the example given in the docs, and did it work? E.g., `(keybinding "c:a" (λ (editor evt) (send editor insert "!")))`

Comment: Does `~~~~~` mean something?

Comment: I tried to add (keybinding "tab" (λ (editor evt) (send editor insert "!"))) and it work. But (keybinding "tab" (λ (editor evt) (send editor Complete Word))) doesn't work.

Comment: So is it `"tab"` or `"Complete Word"` that doesn't work?

Comment: I think it just not recognize "Complete Word"

Comment: Why don't you just try, to be sure? Also, why did you expect that "Complete Word" would work? Is it written so somewhere in docs? (if so, then please provide a link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`auto-complete`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/framework/Text.html?q=auto-complete#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._framework%2Fmain..rkt%29._text~3aautocomplete~3c~25~3e%29._auto-complete%29%29) instead:

```
(keybinding "tab" (λ(editor event) (send editor auto-complete)))
```

Finding the correct functions for keybinding is a bit of a trial and error process, to my experience. The function names as written in the menu "Edit/Keybindings/Show active keybindings" (approximate translation from French) are not always the correct ones it seems.
In particular, here it is written `"Word completion"` but it does not seem to work for me, whereas `"TeX compress"` does work (but has a different function).

Comment: Actually,i found this example of "How to bind a menu item (based on its name)" was work to me,and the codes is:(menu-bind "tab" "Complete Word").But i think your solution is more simple.Anyway,thank you for your answer,Metaxal.